# Comparing two different fields in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How to compare two properties in MongoDB, I want to find and delete all those rows where "income per annum" is greater than "savings per annum"??

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#compare-two-fields-from-a-single-document

Answer (score 1):

You can use deleteMany. Documents that pass the filter will be deleted.
For example

*`$expr` is needed because we need to compare 2 fields. The query `$gt` operator takes a field and a value, so here the aggregate `$gt`
is used with `$expr`

```js
db.collection.deleteMany(
  {"$expr": {"$gt": ["$income-per-annum", "$savings-per-annum"]}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.find({
 "$expr": {
  "$gt": [
    "$income",
    "$savings"
   ]
 }
 }).forEach(function(doc){ db.collection.remove(_id:doc._id)})
```

Explained:

Find all affected documents via $expr and loop over them via forEach to remove one by one.